# JPA - Use of entityManager in entity objects

Tags: spring, entitymanager, roo

I removed Spring Roo from my Spring project, it was unnecessary and the build took to much time in eclipse sts. I performed a Push-In and my entity objects now includes the source code of the old Roo files.

Nothing changed more or less, included the PersistentContext management, that seem very strange. In fact, i notice that every time i have to create a query i need to instantiate the entity class in order to get the EntityManager?

In my entity class i have

```
@Configurable
@Entity
@Table(name = "angr_clienti")
public class AngrClienti {

....

@PersistenceContext
    transient EntityManager entityManager;

public static final EntityManager entityManager() {
        EntityManager em = new AngrClienti().entityManager;
        if (em == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)");
        return em;
    }

public static List<AngrClienti> findAllAngrClientis() {
        return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM AngrClienti o", AngrClienti.class).getResultList();
    }
```

It is strange that every time i call findAllAngrClientis() it calls method entityManager() that instantiates a new AngrClienti() object to access the entity manager.

```
new AngrClienti().entityManager;
```

I think it is very memory consuming, so why?

Answer (score 0):

Well, how else would you propose to implement the static `EntityManager` method?

I'm not sure why you think creating a new instance of `AngriClienti` is expensive. `new AngrClienti().entityManager` simply ensures a new `EntityManager`  is obtained for each unit of work. And since the object is not retained, it is not particularly memory-consuming.

In any case, Active Records are now considered an anti-pattern. If I were you, I'd consider switching to repositories instead.

Comment: I have always used Repository with JPA, this is the first time i face up with Active Records. Actually, Spring Roo has generated Active Record classes, and now that i removed Spring Roo from my Project, i have to manage them. Moving to Repository involves too much effort, for this reason i put the question, i want to be sure it is sustainable